# How to implement horizontal auto scaling in GKE autopilot based on a custom metric

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster on GKE autopilot

I have pods that do the following - Wait for a job, run the job (This can take minutes or hours), Then go to Pod Succeeded State which will cause Kubernetes to restart the pod.

The number of pods I need is variable depending on how many users are on the platform. Each user can request a job that needs a pod to run.

I don't want users to have to wait for pods to scale up so I want to keep a number of extra pods ready and waiting to execute.

The application my pods are running can be in 3 states - { `waiting for job`, `running job`, `completed job`}

Scaling up is fine as I can just use the scale API and always request to have a certain percentage of pods in `waiting for job` state

When scaling down I want to ensure that Kubernetes doesn't kill any pods that are in the `running job` state.

Should I implement a Custom Horizontal Pod Autoscaler?

Can I configure custom probes for my pod's application state?

I could use also use pod priority or a preStop hook

Comment: Could you describe your application a bit more?  For example, what are users submitting to trigger a job?  And what do those jobs need access to?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure horizontal Pod autoscaling to ensure that Kubernetes doesn't kill any pods.

**Steps for configuring horizontal pod scaling**:

Create the Deployment, apply the nginx.yaml manifest,Run the following command:

```
  kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml
```

**Autoscaling based on resources utilization**

1-Go to the Workloads page in Cloud Console.

2-Click the name of the nginx Deployment.

3-Click list **Actions > Autoscale**.

4-Specify the following values:

-**Minimum number of replicas**: 1

-**Maximum number of replicas**: 10

-**Auto Scaling metric**: CPU

-**Target**: 50

-**Unit**: %

5-Click **Done**.

6-Click **Autoscale**.

To get a list of Horizontal Pod Autoscalers in the cluster, use the following command:

```
kubectl get hpa
```

Guide on how to [Configure](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/horizontal-pod-autoscaling#using-gcloud-config) horizontal pod autoscaling.

You can also refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics?_ga=2.247696647.-1823147699.1578008229#custom-metric_2) of auto-scaling rules for the GKE autopilot cluster using a custom metric on the Cloud Console.